# Is it possible to create and schedule Sql server jobs using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to develop a system like SQLServer reporting services without using reporting services of SQLServer.
I want to know how to create and schedule job using stored procedure.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017#TSQL

Comment: So, what are you asking here? *"What alternatives to SSRS are there for SQL Server?"* That would be off topic for Stack Overflow I'm afraid. Expand your post please, and ask a question. It's what's SO is for after all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call msdb.dbo.sp_add_job to create Job in Stored Procedure.

Comment: I want to schedule jobs without using predefined tables of reporting server

Comment: Can you please give more detail

Comment: @Yasa msdb isn't part of reporting services.

Comment: i am able to create job using msdb.dbo.sp_add_job  but i haven't find option for scheduling the job.

Comment: @Yasa look into SQL Server Agent.

Comment: i don't want to manually schedule job, I want to schedule job using procedure

Comment: Thrn why haven't you read Squirrels comment about SAl Server Agents documentation? :)

Comment: You need to find stored procedure via which we can start JOB.

Comment: i have found that but i want to know that how is that stored procedure get automatically triggered.

Comment: can you please give any example I did not understand your comment.

Comment: i want job to get automatically start at specified interval and i want to do all this using procedure without using predefined procedures that sql server has provided

Comment: Job can only be schedule by sql predefined stored procedures.